# i am not able to get xpath of an element using tag a and ng click <a class="item" ng-click="setCurrentScreen('Contacts')">

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<a class="item" ng-click="setCurrentScreen('Contacts')">


WebElement contact_view= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@ng-click='setCurrentScreen('Contacts')']"));
```

please help me to get xpath of this element

Below is my HTML code.

```
<a class="item" ng-click="setCurrentScreen('Contacts')">
 <img ng-src="img/clutto/Contacts_Icon_Selected.png" 

src="img/clutto/Contacts_Icon_Selected.png"> </a> this tag a and ng click
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with the quotes inside the locator. Try something like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@ng-click=\"setCurrentScreen('Contacts')\"]"));
```